# How to generate jar labrary using Andorid Studio (Gradle)

Tags: jar, gradle, android-studio, android-library

I have an android library which I am developing using android studio.
It depends on Android SDK but does not have any resources, assets, other dependencies.

Now I want to produce a jar library for this android library, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `File > Project Structure > Artifacts`, then click plus sign and choose `From modules with dependencies...`